# Kafka Consumer Report Creation

Tags: java, report, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have 4 consumer pods reading and processing data from a topic which sends around 1000records by reading a file everyday

so my job is to configure the consumer logic in such a way that at the end of processing the 1000records by the 4 different pods, i need to send an email with a SINGLE attachment which contains the status of all 1000records weather it got processed or not.

The problem i’m facing is that, since there are multiple pods the messages get consumed by each one of them automatically and report will be sent multiple times.

1. storing in a file and appending the records won’t work bcoz there might be a deadlock issue.
2. Is storing  the results in DB and running job, the only way!???

Comment: How about to send all the reports from all your consumers to another topic to be aggregated to a single file? This way you don't need a DB and don't need to think about shared file. You might need to think about the number of your pods to let the aggregator to know how many files to wait for collecting. Either way doesn't look like Kafka-related question at all...